# pgRouting shortest_path get uniqe osm_id values

Tags: sql

I have sql:

```
SELECT osm_id, vertex_id
   FROM ways
   JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
      SELECT gid AS id, 
          source::int4 AS source, 
          target::int4 AS target, 
          length::float8 AS cost
      FROM ways',
      7856,
      18774,
      false,
      false)) AS route
   ON
   ways.gid = route.edge_id 
   order by vertex_id
```

It produces something like this:

```
osm_id;vertex_id
5024380;6223
5024380;6224
5024380;6225
5024380;6226
175339584;6227
5024380;6230
5024380;6231
5024380;6232
38521651;6233
5024380;6234
```

You can see, that osm_id is not unique. I neet `osm_id` ordered by `vertex_id`. How i can get only unique `osm_id` values ordered by `vertex_id`. I don't need `vertex_id` column. Need only `osm_id`. I tried `group by` clause but that doesn't works. Fallowing query:

```
SELECT distinct osm_id
   FROM ways
   JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
      SELECT gid AS id, 
          source::int4 AS source, 
          target::int4 AS target, 
          length::float8 AS cost
      FROM ways',
      7856,
      18774,
      false,
      false)) AS route
   ON
   ways.gid = route.edge_id 
   --group by osm_id
   order by vertex_id
```

gives error:

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 21:    order by vertex_id 
                     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
SQL state: 42P10
Character: 420
```

Comment: What table does vertex_id  come from? Ways or the 'route'/shortest_path subquery?

Comment: from shortest_path subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT osm_id
   FROM ways
   JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
      SELECT gid AS id, 
          source::int4 AS source, 
          target::int4 AS target, 
          length::float8 AS cost
      FROM ways',
      7856,
      18774,
      false,
      false)) AS route
   ON
   ways.gid = route.edge_id 
   GROUP BY osm_id
   ORDER BY min(vertex_id)
```